# Silverlight 3 Business application : How to pass query string from Mainpage to About Page?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Main page consists of a listbox, frame and few hyperlinks. On clicking hyperlink, appropriate page is loaded in the frame.

How can I pass the selected item value of the listbox on Main page to page being loaded(ex: About page) through query string in silverlight 3?

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your architecture? Are main page and about page two pages within the same silverlight app? Two seperate applications on different pages? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Thank you Graeme Bradbury for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.urimapping(VS.95).aspx) page, you can specify a query string in the format

```
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Products/{type}" 
  MappedUri="/Views/ProductDetail.xaml?producttype={type}">
</uriMapper:UriMapping>
```

I do not know how to link the type to a value through XAML but on navigation to that page, you can add an OnClick event instead of a navigateuri. In the OnClick event you will specify something like the following:

```
private void Link2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri x = new Uri(String.Format(/Products/{0},yourcombo.SelectedItem), UriKind.Relative);

    //ContentFrame is the Navigation Frame
    ContentFrame.Navigate(x);
}
```

This will navigate to the ProductDetail.xaml page. From here you can get the producttype value by using `string type = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["producttype"];`

Tim Heuer also has an excellent [web cast](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/navigation-framework/) on the navigation solutions.